# Make table heading sortable by clicking heading with angularjs ngtable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

I am using angularjs ng-table module. I would like to make a table sortable by clicking the heading. Here is the relevant html code.

```
<div ng-controller="ViewCtrl" class="container">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>name</th>            
            <th>changeInPercent</th>
            <th>Ratio</th>
        </tr>

        <thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="stk in $data">
            <td data-title="'name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'" " >
                {{stk.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'changeInPercent'" >
                {{stk.changeInPercent}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Ratio'" >
                {{stk.Ratio}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The relevant controller code looks like this;

```
.controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'configuration', 'ngTableParams',
    function ($scope, $http, $configuration, ngTableParams) {
        var tableData = [];
        //Table configuration
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 100
        }, {
            total: tableData.length,
            //Returns the data for rendering
            getData: function ($defer, params) {                    
                var url = $configuration.webroot + '/fsa/list?list=XXlist';
                $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    tableData = response.data;
                    $defer.resolve(tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    params.total(tableData.length);
                });
            }
        });
    }])
```

The table data is displayed correctly. I expect the name column to be sortable by clicking on it. However, the name column remains unsortable. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and/or a working jsFiddle ?

Comment: @Shitsu, the data is retrieved from a REST API server. Hard to provide a working jsFiddle. However, I have provided the relevant controller code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it !

Just remove the `thead` element. It will be constructed automatically with the titles you mention in the `data-title` attributes.

Edit: here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/byLgm2cf/2/). You will probably need to add some processing in the `getData`, as in this snippet:

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  // ...
}, {
  // ...
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    // apply sorting and such 
    $scope.tableData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.tableData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.tableData;
    $scope.tableData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.tableData, params.filter()) : $scope.tableData;
    $scope.tableData = $scope.tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
    $defer.resolve($scope.tableData);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Upvoted. I removed the thead. However, it did not work in my case. I suspect the problem may lie in the controller. From this tutorial http://4dev.tech/2015/08/tutorial-basic-datatable-sorting-filtering-and-pagination-with-angularjs-and-ng-table/, something like `params.sorting()` needs to be added.

Comment: In your JSfiddle,  this line `$scope.tableData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.tableData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.users;` puzzles me. It seems that `$scope.users` can be anything. If I replace this line with `$scope.tableData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.tableData, params.orderBy()) : '';` , the code will still work.

Comment: But your previous answer is not wrong. The code still works no matter what the value. This is what puzzles me.

Comment: It works because in our case, `params.sorting()` is always true. Try to remove the `sortable` attribute and it should crash ^^.

Comment: Would it be more "correct" if we use this line `$scope.tableData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.tableData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.tableData, 0` to give some dummy result in case `params.sorting()` is false?

Answer (score 2):

You don't close the td properly:

```
 <td data-title="'name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
```

Comment: Sorry, I checked my original code. I did close the tag properly. Did not copy the code over to StackOverflow properly. My careless fault. I have edited the question to cover the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in both your html and controller code.

Remove thead and tr elements from the html code;

```
<div ng-controller="ViewCtrl" class="container">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="stk in $data">
            <td data-title="'name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'" " >
                {{stk.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'changeInPercent'" >
                {{stk.changeInPercent}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Ratio'" >
                {{stk.Ratio}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Add params.sorting() to the controller code.

```
.controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'configuration', 'ngTableParams',
    function ($scope, $http, $configuration, ngTableParams) {
        var tableData = [];
        //Table configuration
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 100
        }, {
            total: tableData.length,
            //Returns the data for rendering
            getData: function ($defer, params) {                    
                var url = $configuration.webroot + '/fsa/list?list=XXlist';
                $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    tableData = response.data;
                    tableData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(tableData, params.orderBy()) : tableData;
                    tableData = tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());   
                    $defer.resolve(tableData);
                    params.total(tableData.length);
                });
            }
        });
    }])
```